# day of month must be between 1 and last day of month while using ADD_MONTHS in CASE

Tags: sql, oracle

Anything wrong in below SQL `CASE`, I am getting this error:

```
[Error] Execution (209: 8): ORA-01847: day of month must be between 1 and last day of month
```

```sql
CASE WHEN TIER = 1 THEN ADD_MONTHS (TARGET_DATE, 12) 
     WHEN (TIER = 2 OR TIER = 0 OR TIER IS NULL) THEN ADD_MONTHS (TARGET_DATE, 24)
     ELSE ADD_MONTHS (TARGET_DATE, 36) END TARGET_DATE
```

Comment: What type of column is TARGET_DATE? Is it really a date column? Then, are you certain that this case statement leads to the error? I can't be sure, seeing it is not a complete SQL statement. Meaning: does the SQL run without a hitch when you comment out only that case ?

Comment: Its DATE column only, ADD_MONTHS function causing the issue.

Comment: Cannot replicate the issue [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Fq8WDtn2). Please [edit] your question and include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements and a complete `SELECT` query that replicates the problem. Are you sure that (a) the column is a `DATE` and (b) that the problem is not somewhere else in your query?

Comment: I just tried select add_months(to_date('29/02/2024','dd/mm/yyyy'),36)
from dual; and it works, giving 28.02.2027. So it caters for February being shorter in some years. Even adding 1 to 31.01.2023 gives 28.02.2023. So I'm not sure that this ADD_MONTHS is giving the error.

Comment: Can you reply to the first comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks OK. No errors and result as expected. Shouldd be something else causing the error.The strange thing is that whatever enters the CASE expression there are always 6 months added to  target date !?!?

```sql
WITH
    tbl AS
        ( Select LEVEL - 1 "TIER", To_Date('28.08.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy') "TARGET_DATE" From Dual Connect By LEVEL <= 3 UNION ALL
      Select LEVEL - 1 "TIER", To_Date('29.08.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy') "TARGET_DATE" From Dual Connect By LEVEL <= 3 UNION ALL
      Select LEVEL - 1 "TIER", To_Date('30.08.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy') "TARGET_DATE" From Dual Connect By LEVEL <= 3 UNION ALL
      Select LEVEL - 1 "TIER", To_Date('31.08.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy') "TARGET_DATE" From Dual Connect By LEVEL <= 3 UNION ALL
      Select LEVEL - 1 "TIER", To_Date('01.09.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy') "TARGET_DATE" From Dual Connect By LEVEL <= 3)
Select  TIER, 
        TARGET_DATE, 
        CASE WHEN TIER = 1 THEN ADD_MONTHS (TARGET_DATE, 6) 
            WHEN (TIER = 2 OR TIER = 0 OR TIER IS NULL) THEN ADD_MONTHS (TARGET_DATE, 6)
            ELSE ADD_MONTHS (TARGET_DATE, 6) END "NEW_TARGET_DATE"
From    tbl
Order By TARGET_DATE, TIER
--
--  R e s u l t :
--        TIER TARGET_DA NEW_TARGE
--  ---------- --------- ---------
--           0 28-AUG-23 28-FEB-24
--           1 28-AUG-23 28-FEB-24
--           2 28-AUG-23 28-FEB-24
--           0 29-AUG-23 29-FEB-24
--           1 29-AUG-23 29-FEB-24
--           2 29-AUG-23 29-FEB-24
--           0 30-AUG-23 29-FEB-24
--           1 30-AUG-23 29-FEB-24
--           2 30-AUG-23 29-FEB-24
--           0 31-AUG-23 29-FEB-24
--           1 31-AUG-23 29-FEB-24
--           2 31-AUG-23 29-FEB-24
--           0 01-SEP-23 01-MAR-24
--           1 01-SEP-23 01-MAR-24
--           2 01-SEP-23 01-MAR-24
```

Updated CASE still works fine.

```sql
WITH
    tbl AS
        ( Select LEVEL - 1 "TIER", To_Date('28.08.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy') "TARGET_DATE" From Dual Connect By LEVEL <= 8)
Select  TIER, 
        TARGET_DATE, 
        CASE WHEN TIER = 1 THEN ADD_MONTHS (TARGET_DATE, 12) 
     WHEN (TIER = 2 OR TIER = 0 OR TIER IS NULL) THEN ADD_MONTHS (TARGET_DATE, 24)
     ELSE ADD_MONTHS (TARGET_DATE, 36) END "NEW_TARGET_DATE"
From    tbl
Order By TARGET_DATE, TIER
--
--  R e s u l t :
--        TIER TARGET_DA NEW_TARGE
--  ---------- --------- ---------
--           0 28-AUG-23 28-AUG-25
--           1 28-AUG-23 28-AUG-24
--           2 28-AUG-23 28-AUG-25
--           3 28-AUG-23 28-AUG-26
--           4 28-AUG-23 28-AUG-26
--           5 28-AUG-23 28-AUG-26
--           6 28-AUG-23 28-AUG-26
--           7 28-AUG-23 28-AUG-26
```